# how to subtract each element in a ndarray with each and every element of another ndarray in numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

for example I have,

```
a = np.array([[0.4 , 0.87, 0.24, 0.1 ],
              [0.6 , 0.93, 0.34, 0.98],
              [0.5 , 0.32, 0.09, 0.99],
              [0.4 , 0.11, 0.18, 0.65],
              [0.5 , 0.98, 0.47, 0.78]])

b = np.array([[0.6 , 0.93 ,0.34 ,0.98],
              [0.7 , 0.47 ,0.43, 0.76]])
```

I want to subtract each element of 'b' from 'a' but without using for loop. I used for loop to get the output but I have several rows and consuming more time.Is there any way of doing it effectively with less time in numpy?

I expect the output to be like :

```
array([[ 0.2 ,  0.06,  0.1 ,  0.88],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.1 ,  0.61,  0.25, -0.01],
       [ 0.2 ,  0.82,  0.16,  0.33],
       [ 0.1 , -0.05, -0.13,  0.2 ],
       [ 0.3 , -0.4 ,  0.19,  0.66],
       [ 0.1 , -0.46,  0.09, -0.22],
       [ 0.2 ,  0.15,  0.34, -0.23],
       [ 0.3 ,  0.36,  0.25,  0.11],
       [ 0.2 , -0.51, -0.04, -0.02]])
```

Comment: Do you really want the result to be (10,4)?  Why not (2,5,4)?

Comment: Yeah I need (10,4). because based on this result I have processed the rest of my code. If I get this result it would save my time as this is taking most of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order will be different from what you have shown, but the values will be the same with the following method:

```
>>> np.tile(b, (len(a),1)) - np.tile(a,(len(b),1))

array([[ 0.2 ,  0.06,  0.1 ,  0.88],
       [ 0.1 , -0.46,  0.09, -0.22],
       [ 0.1 ,  0.61,  0.25, -0.01],
       [ 0.3 ,  0.36,  0.25,  0.11],
       [ 0.1 , -0.05, -0.13,  0.2 ],
       [ 0.3 , -0.4 ,  0.19,  0.66],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.2 ,  0.15,  0.34, -0.23],
       [ 0.2 ,  0.82,  0.16,  0.33],
       [ 0.2 , -0.51, -0.04, -0.02]])
```

**Explanation**:

What the code does is create repeats of `a` and `b`, so that for each row of `a`, you have each row of `b`

```
>>> np.tile(b, (len(a),1))
array([[0.6 , 0.93, 0.34, 0.98],
       [0.7 , 0.47, 0.43, 0.76],
       [0.6 , 0.93, 0.34, 0.98],
       [0.7 , 0.47, 0.43, 0.76],
       [0.6 , 0.93, 0.34, 0.98],
       [0.7 , 0.47, 0.43, 0.76],
       [0.6 , 0.93, 0.34, 0.98],
       [0.7 , 0.47, 0.43, 0.76],
       [0.6 , 0.93, 0.34, 0.98],
       [0.7 , 0.47, 0.43, 0.76]])

>>> np.tile(a, (len(b),1))
array([[0.4 , 0.87, 0.24, 0.1 ],
       [0.6 , 0.93, 0.34, 0.98],
       [0.5 , 0.32, 0.09, 0.99],
       [0.4 , 0.11, 0.18, 0.65],
       [0.5 , 0.98, 0.47, 0.78],
       [0.4 , 0.87, 0.24, 0.1 ],
       [0.6 , 0.93, 0.34, 0.98],
       [0.5 , 0.32, 0.09, 0.99],
       [0.4 , 0.11, 0.18, 0.65],
       [0.5 , 0.98, 0.47, 0.78]])
```

Then it's just a matter of subtracting.

**[EDIT]**, since you say your order needs to be preserved, you can do:

```
>>> np.repeat(b, len(a),axis=0) - np.tile(a,(len(b),1))
array([[ 0.2 ,  0.06,  0.1 ,  0.88],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.1 ,  0.61,  0.25, -0.01],
       [ 0.2 ,  0.82,  0.16,  0.33],
       [ 0.1 , -0.05, -0.13,  0.2 ],
       [ 0.3 , -0.4 ,  0.19,  0.66],
       [ 0.1 , -0.46,  0.09, -0.22],
       [ 0.2 ,  0.15,  0.34, -0.23],
       [ 0.3 ,  0.36,  0.25,  0.11],
       [ 0.2 , -0.51, -0.04, -0.02]])
```

Comment: The order must be preserved. it has connection to my data frame indexes.

Comment: See my edits, that should take care of it (use `repeat` instead of `tile` to repeat each element of `b` consecutively)

Comment: With broadcasting you can get a (2,5,4) array which can be reshaped to (10,4): `(b[:,None,:]-a[None,:,:]).reshape(-1,4)`.

Comment: @hpaulj That is nicer, I agree!